Heroku: Cannot GET / - Issue with Serving Static Files and Routing in Node.js App
I'm trying to deploy my Node.js application on Heroku, but I'm encountering a `Cannot GET /` error when accessing the root URL. The app works perfectly on my local machine. Here are the details of my setup:
## `server.js`:
const http = require('http');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = require('./app');
require('dotenv').config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Import website page routes
const accueilRouter = require("./src/routes/home/accueil.routes");
const serviceRouter = require("./src/routes/services/services.routes");
const habitatRouter = require("./src/routes/habitats/habitats.routes");
const contactRouter = require("./src/routes/contact/contact.routes");
const adminDashboardRouter = require("./src/routes/dashboard/admin/adminDash.routes");
const employeeDashboardRouter = require("./src/routes/dashboard/employee/employeeDash.routes");
const veterinarianDashboardRouter = require("./src/routes/dashboard/veterinarian/veterinarianDash.routes");

// Import API routes
const foodAPIRouter = require("./src/api/v1/food/foodAPI.routes");
const serviceAPIRouter = require("./src/api/v1/services/serviceAPI.routes");
const habitatAPIRouter = require("./src/api/v1/habitat/habitatAPI.routes");
const consommationAPIRouter = require("./src/api/v1/consommation/consommationAPI.routes");
const animalAPIRouter = require("./src/api/v1/animal/animalAPI.routes");
const healthRecordAPIRouter = require("./src/api/v1/healthRecord/healthRecordAPI.routes");
const visitorReviewAPIRouter = require("./src/api/v1/visitorReview/visitorReview.routes");
const manageEmployeeAPIRouter = require("./src/api/v1/employee/manageEmployeeAPI.routes");
const manageVeterinarianAPIRouter = require("./src/api/v1/veterinarian/manageVeterinarianAPI.routes");
const animalViewsRouter = require('./src/api/v1/animal/animalViewsAPI.routes');

// Import login & logout routes
const loginRouter = require("./src/auth/api.login");
const logoutRouter = require("./src/auth/api.logout");

// Définir les routes principales
app.use("/accueil", accueilRouter);
app.use("/services", serviceRouter);
app.use("/habitats", habitatRouter);
app.use("/contact", contactRouter);

// Define user dashboard routes
app.use("/admin", adminDashboardRouter);
app.use("/employee", employeeDashboardRouter);
app.use("/veterinarian", veterinarianDashboardRouter);

// Define Arcadia API routes
app.use("/api/v1/services", serviceAPIRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/foods", foodAPIRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/habitats", habitatAPIRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/consommation", consommationAPIRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/animal", animalAPIRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/healthRecord", healthRecordAPIRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/visitorReview", visitorReviewAPIRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/manageEmployeeAccount", manageEmployeeAPIRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/manageVetrinarianAccount", manageVeterinarianAPIRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/animalCount', animalViewsRouter);

// Define login & logout features
app.use("/api/login", loginRouter);
app.use("/api/logout", logoutRouter);

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI)
  .then(() => console.log('Connexion à MongoDB réussie !'))
  .catch(err => console.log('Connexion à MongoDB échouée !', err));

// Utiliser HTTP pour démarrer le serveur
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});

## `app.js`:
const express = require("express");
const passport = require("passport");
const session = require("express-session");
const flash = require("express-flash");
const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config();

const morgan = require("morgan");
const path = require("path");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const strategy = require("./src/config/passportJwtStrategie.config");

const app = express();
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const methodOverride = require("method-override");

// CORS options
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "https://127.0.0.1:3000",
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(cookieParser())

// Session configuration
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    name: "session",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true },
  })
);

// Passport strategy configuration
strategy(passport);

// Flash messages
app.use(flash());

app.use(helmet());
app.use(morgan("dev"));

// Serve static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use("/uploads", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "uploads")));

// Set view engine
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "src", "views"));

// Serve static files in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'front_end', 'build')));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'front_end', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}

// Définir la route principale pour "/"
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/accueil');
});

module.exports = app;

accueil.routes.js :
const express = require("express");
const accueilRouter = express.Router();
const {
  fetchServicesData,
  fetchAnimalsData,
  fetchHabitatData,
  fetchReviewsData,
} = require("../../utils/apiClient");

const decodeData = require("../../utils/decodeData");


accueilRouter.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const animals = await fetchAnimalsData();
    const services = await fetchServicesData();
    const habitats = await fetchHabitatData();
    const reviews = await fetchReviewsData();
    const approvedReviews = reviews.filter(review => review.approved === true);

    const decodedAnimal = decodeData(animals);
    const decodedService = decodeData(services);
    const decodedHabitats = decodeData(habitats);
    const decodedApprovedReviews = decodeData(approvedReviews);
    
    const errorMessagesLogin = req.flash('error_msg_login');
    const errorMessagesReview = req.flash('error_msg_review');

    res.render("layouts/accueil", {
      title: "Page d'accueil",
      animals: decodedAnimal,
      services: decodedService,
      habitats: decodedHabitats,
      reviews: decodedApprovedReviews,
      errorMessagesLogin: errorMessagesLogin,
      errorMessagesReview: errorMessagesReview
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.render("layouts/accueil", {
      title: "Page d'accueil",
      errorMessagesLogin: req.flash('error_msg_login'),
      errorMessagesReview: req.flash('error_msg_review'),
      animals: [],
      services: [],
      habitats: [],
      reviews: [],
    });
  }
});

module.exports = accueilRouter;

HEROKU LOG :
2024-05-17T16:29:36.325488+00:00 app[web.1]: You are listening to port 11454
2024-05-17T16:29:36.465565+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2024-05-17T16:35:19.151773+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=arcadia-broceliande-56a7579e973d.herokuapp.com request_id=b19af80f-ece8-4aee-8704-db0d9325ab15 fwd="78.195.32.108" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=712 protocol=https
2024-05-17T16:35:19.152272+00:00 app[web.1]: GET / 404 139 - 1.936 ms
2024-05-17T16:39:24.480544+00:00 app[web.1]: GET / 404 139 - 0.552 ms
2024-05-17T16:39:24.481362+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=arcadia-broceliande-56a7579e973d.herokuapp.com request_id=8877d3e5-5d1e-4577-8570-5f36fef6a550 fwd="78.195.32.108" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=712 protocol=https
2024-05-17T16:39:32.920717+00:00 app[web.1]: GET / 404 139 - 0.299 ms
2024-05-17T16:39:32.921012+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=arcadia-broceliande-56a7579e973d.herokuapp.com request_id=93105be1-5f59-451c-9030-fadde554278d fwd="78.195.32.108" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=712 protocol=https
2024-05-17T16:39:50.460122+00:00 app[web.1]: GET / 404 139 - 0.333 ms
2024-05-17T16:39:50.460511+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=arcadia-broceliande-56a7579e973d.herokuapp.com request_id=27d64166-f324-4b5b-829f-832d47bd2478 fwd="78.195.32.108" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=404 bytes=712 protocol=https
2024-05-17T16:41:53.879542+00:00 app[web.1]: GET / 404 139 - 0.247 ms
2024-05-17T16:41:53.879763+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=arcadia-broceliande-56a7579e973d.herokuapp.com request_id=a34d5b72-03ed-4641-a319-ad823b4893c8 fwd="78.195.32.108" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=404 bytes=712 protocol=https
2024-05-17T16:41:57.690327+00:00 app[web.1]: GET / 404 139 - 0.343 ms
2024-05-17T16:41:57.691000+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=arcadia-broceliande-56a7579e973d.herokuapp.com request_id=5e4f3d31-fe00-4f48-92f5-55a9f021e4b2 fwd="78.195.32.108" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=712 protocol=https
2024-05-17T16:47:37.057954+00:00 app[web.1]: GET / 404 139 - 0.284 ms
2024-05-17T16:47:37.058158+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=arcadia-broceliande-56a7579e973d.herokuapp.com request_id=e6e434bf-8db0-42b9-b2e6-01c7a8bcccb0 fwd="78.195.32.108" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=712 protocol=https
2024-05-17T16:47:48.922428+00:00 app[web.1]: GET / 404 139 - 0.244 ms
2024-05-17T16:47:48.922865+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=arcadia-broceliande-56a7579e973d.herokuapp.com request_id=4d285d5d-635f-4d77-ba9c-ac070366c181 fwd="78.195.32.108" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=404 bytes=712 protocol=https
2024-05-17T16:50:02.717129+00:00 app[web.1]: GET / 404 139 - 0.471 ms

Problem
When I deploy the app to Heroku and try to access the root URL, I get a Cannot GET / error. Here is what I've tried so far:

Ensured the route for / is defined to redirect to /accueil.

Configured the app to serve static files in production.

Checked the .gitignore to ensure the build directory is not being ignored.

Verified that the app works perfectly on my local machine.


I expected the root URL / to redirect to /accueil and show the homepage. Instead, I get a Cannot GET / error.
